# In bash, how to get the current status of set -x?

Tags: bash, set, built-in

I would like to set -x temporarily in my script and then return in to the original state.

Is there a way to do it without starting new subshell?
Something like

```
echo_was_on=.......
... ...
if $echo_was_on; then set -x; else set +x; fi
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can check the value of `$-` to see the current options; if it contains an x, it was set. You can check like so:

```
old_setting=${-//[^x]/}
...
if [[ -n "$old_setting" ]]; then set -x; else set +x; fi
```

In case it's not familiar to you: the `${}` above is a [Bash Substring Replacement](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), which takes the variable `-` and replaces anything that's not an `x` with nothing, leaving just the `x` behind (or nothing, if there was no x)

Answer (score 17):

```
reset_x=false
if ! [ -o xtrace ]; then
    set -x
    reset_x=true
fi

# do stuff

"$reset_x" && set +x
```

You test a shell option with the `-o` test (using `[` as above or with `test -o`).  If the `xtrace` option isn't set (`set +x`), then set it and set a flag to turn it off later.

In a function, you could even have set a `RETURN` trap to reset the setting when the function returns:

```
foo () {
    if ! [ -o xtrace ]; then
        set -x
        trap 'set +x' RETURN
    fi

    # rest of function body here
}
```

Comment: What shells support it? It doesn't seem to be listed among POSIX shell test operators: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html.

Comment: @skozin `bash` supports it.  The question was specifically about `bash`, both in title, and by tags.

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed it :) Yup, for Bash it seems like a proper way to do it.

Comment: @skozin No worries.

Comment: Updated my answer with link to this one.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I can't quickly figure out why your solution only works when I use double brackets instead of your suggested single ones. If I just leave single as in your post, then no matter if xtrace enabled or not the if [ ! -o xtrace]; always true.  I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, bash --version: 5.0.17(1)-release, thanks!

Comment: @DmitryShevkoplyas Thanks for finding an interesting bug! The `-o` test tests whether an option is set or not, but if you use `! -o`, the `-o` test is interpreted as "or" (it changes meaning with the number of arguments inside `[ ... ]`). The solution is to switch to `[[ ... ]]` as you figured out, or to do as I now do in my answer, i.e. to negate the result of the test outside the brackets.

Answer (score 14):

Or in a case statement

```
 case $- in
   *x* ) echo "X is set, do something here" ;;
   * )   echo "x NOT set" ;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 10):

Here are re-usable functions, based on [@shellter's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565058/804678) and [@glenn jackman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14574113/804678) answers:

```sh
is_shell_attribute_set() { # attribute, like "e"
  case "$-" in
    *"$1"*) return 0 ;;
    *)    return 1 ;;
  esac
}


is_shell_option_set() { # option, like "pipefail"
  case "$(set -o | grep "$1")" in
    *on) return 0 ;;
    *)   return 1 ;;
  esac
}
```

Usage example:

```sh
set -e
if is_shell_attribute_set e; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # yes

set +e
if is_shell_attribute_set e; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # no

set -o pipefail
if is_shell_option_set pipefail; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # yes

set +o pipefail
if is_shell_option_set pipefail; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi # no
```

---

**Update**: for Bash, `test -o` is a better way to accomplish the same, see [@Kusalananda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564746/in-bash-how-to-get-the-current-status-of-set-x#50668339).

Comment: This is essentially `test -o OPTION`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, see my question to your answer. Apart from that, it seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
case $(set -o | grep xtrace | cut -f2) in
    off) do something ;;
    on)  do another thing ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

less verbose

```
[ ${-/x} != ${-} ] && tracing=1 || tracing=0
```

Answer (score 2):

This should answer exactly the question, provided your okay with the bash extension (non POSIX) and you bash version supports it.

```
[[ $- =~ x ]] && echo_was_on=true || echo_was_on=false
```

Comment: Since you are the only answer citing POSIX, the [POSIX way](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to do it could be `[ -z "${-%%*x*}" ] && echo on`; which would be working for ash, dash, etc.

Comment: Thanks @bufh for the POSIX way.
All four Remove Pattern operators can work here.
Also without double quotes.
`[ -z ${-%*x*} ]`, `[ -z ${-%%*x*} ]`, `[ -z ${-#*x*} ]`, `[ -z ${-##*x*} ]`.
Please correct me if I am wrong.