# Check current bash verbosity

Tags: bash, verbosity

I know bash can be set to verbose mode by using `set -v`, however I want to write a function that doesn't run in verbose mode even if called from a verbosed script.

While I'm aware I could disable verbosity by using `set +v` at the start of the function and end it with `set -v`, that would mean my function will set any script that calls it to verbose, even if it wasn't verbose before calling it.

Ideally I'd check the verbosity level at the start of the function, disable verbosity, and revert the verbosity change at the end of the function.

Is there a way to find current verbosity level?

Comment: From my point of view, it's only on and off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [[ $- =~ v ]]; then 
  echo "verbose enabled"
else
  echo "verbose disabled"
fi
```

---

> `$-`: Contains the current set of enabled options. See: `help set`

Answer (score 1):

```
if test -o verbose; then
   echo 'shell is running in verbose mode'
else
   echo 'shell is not running in verbose mode'
fi
```

or, equivalently,

```
if [[ -o verbose ]]; then
   echo 'shell is running in verbose mode'
else
   echo 'shell is not running in verbose mode'
fi
```

The built-in `test` utility in `bash` is able to test whether a shell option is set or not using `-o OPTION`.  See `help test` in an interactive `bash` shell, or read about it is the `bash` manual.

Your function may look like

```
foo () {
    if [[ -o verbose ]]; then
        set +v
        trap 'set -v' RETURN
    fi

    # do stuff
}
```

This detects whether `-v` is active when the function is called. If it is, it is turned off and a `RETURN` trap is installed that will switch it back on again when the function returns (at the end of the function, or by an explicit `return` statement).

Answer (score 0):

Checking verbose mode option is the same as checking any other bash option, see  [In bash, how to get the current status of set -x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564746/in-bash-how-to-get-the-current-status-of-set-x) .

Try this:

```
func() {
   local old_verbosity_level=${-//[^v]}
   set +v
   ...
   if [ -n "$old_verbosity_level" ]; then set -v; else set +v; fi
}
```

or more tricky:

```
func() {
   local old_verbosity_level=${-//[^v]}
   set +v
   ...
   ${old_verbosity_level:+set -v}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your function and its usage, you could just limit the scope of option changes with a `(..)` subshell:

```
foo() (
  set +vx
  echo "not verbose"
)

set -v
foo
echo "still verbose"
```